# Using R random number generators in C

Tags: c, r

I'm to call R from a program in C to generate pseudo random numbers. In particular I want to call "rpois". I tried to understand in general how to call the R API but I haven't succeeded.

Out of the box ideas are also welcomed.

Comment: have you had a look here: http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/61617

Comment: How about "Numerical Recipes in C" and write up a Poisson RNG in C instead?

Comment: I am confused how this question is a duplicate if this question regards C, not C++.  Do the answers for C++ provided in response to the earlier question apply equally to C?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I need other distributions as well, and I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.